# Replacing specific pieces of text with visual representations in a readable+writable JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I have a text editor in which the user can define a *pattern* for data. A pattern can contain a reference to another pattern. A simple example would be `{ name: $pattern2 }`, where `$pattern2` refers to a different pattern which will later be substituted into this one. However, patterns are identified by a UUID, not by a name, which makes it unwieldy to use. To compensate, users have a bunch of buttons that insert the UUID into the editor for them. However, UUIDs are not nice to look at.

A visually appealing way might be possible using a `JTextPane` (or `JEditorPane`) to replaces the UUID with a small square containing the referenced pattern's name. The first image below shows what the actual contents of the `Document` are, while the second image shows how I imagine it is displayed to the user, given two other patterns with the names `GoodName` and `Date`.

[image: Raw underlying pattern]
[image: Visualised pattern]

I have tried using the `javax.swing.text.Style` object obtained from `jTextPane.addStyle("", null)`, I tried with a `javax.swing.text.StyleContext`, and I looked at extending `javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument`, but those mostly seem to concern themselves with changing the way the font is rendered. I don't really see a way to render specific text as a non-text shape. Furthermore, I don't see a way of making the reference "atomic", in the sense that the user cannot select and remove half of the UUID, which would reveal the underlying data which I'm trying to keep hidden.

Is anyone aware of a component that supports behaviour like this? Am I overlooking a Swing feature here? Swing has loads of documentation but it's hard to find what you're looking for if you don't know what it's called.

Comment: A drawing JPanel would give you complete control over how the text is displayed.  The disadvantage is that you would be responsible for displaying all text and creating your own editor.  The Oracle tutorial, [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) would get you started, but creating a complete editor from a drawing JPanel would take a good bit of effort.

Comment: The [Document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html) interface would be helpful when creating your own editor.

Comment: Try to add a JComponent to your editor (in your case it would be a JLabel).

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc A custom `JPanel` *could* be a solution, but I think it's way too much work. But I'll have to look into the `Document` interface, because while `StyledDocument` has the limitations I mentioned in my question (i.e. it's basically limited to RTF-type styling), I might be able to overcome that using a custom `Document` class, given that I can create my own hierarchy of elements and such. Unfortunately it doesn't look like there's much material online about how to do that...

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy I'm not sure how I should do that. I mean, running `jTextPane.add(new JLabel("test"))` does absolutely nothing. Is there a specific method you had in mind?

Comment: @FWDekker [Example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java-program-to-insert-a-component-into-a-jtextpane-component)

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy Nice! That's exactly the kind of visual behaviour I'm looking for. Didn't know there was a `setComponent` method. Now making sure it always deletes the ID completely should be easy by overriding `removeString` in a subclass of `DefaultStyledDocument`, and I think I can make sure the component appears to be 1 character wide by setting the `NavigationFilter` on the document.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is a case where a JLayer can be successfully applied.

Instead of replacing the UUIDs with small rectangles, an equally large rectangle containing the name could be drawn over each UUID.

Comment: Hi tniessen, welcome to SO! I think it's an interesting solution, but unfortunately I don't think it will look good to have such large rectangles when there's a short name ("Date" is four characters") covering a UUID (approx. 37 characters). Additionally, I think a JLayer wouldn't (easily) allow me to prevent users from selecting or deleting half of the underlying UUID.

Comment: A solution has to be visually satisfactory, that's for sure. Without this, it would not help if the second problem could somehow be solved with a DocumentFilter.